# Using template<> in argument

Tags: c++, templates

I'm used to the template syntax for a fully specialized template:

```
template<typename T>
struct S {};

template<>
struct S<int> {}; // Fully specialized
```

But I have no idea that I could use it as an argument:

```
void fn(std::function<> lambda){
}

int main() {
  fn([](){ std::cout << "Hello"; });
}
```

Does the above mean "give me a fully specialized std::function as a parameter" ?
Why hasn't it the `template <> std::function` syntax?

Comment: This means "an `std::function` instantiation with all its parameters defaulted". Why `std::function` has default parameters I'm currently looking up.

Comment: @Quentin according to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) it doesn't.

Comment: Does it compile? http://rextester.com/WETU77257

Comment: @Walter indeed. This looks like a leaky library implementation to me.

Answer (score 1):

It appears (see [this documentation of `std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)) that the C++ standard does not provide for a fully specialized version of `std::function<signature>` , i.e. a default such as `signature=void()`. Thus, if your code compiled, then the C++ standard library used was not fully standard compliant. You should file a bug report.

Comment: I don't think that makes the implementation non-compliant, only slightly user-unfriendly.

Comment: @Quentin I'd suggest filing a bug report anyway and let the authors of the library check and decide if that it's indeed what was intended. `NOTABUG`s are not harmful unless there's a flood of them.

Comment: @TheVee yes, I totally agree. Just nitpicking on the vocabulary :)